# Восстановление пароля, если  его забыл пользователь

Tags: email, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите как реализовать данное, пользователь забыл пароль ему надо восстановить его, как сделать это лучше?

- Мой вариант: recover.php

поле для e-mail'a пользователя который забыл пасс, если ввел его мыло то на его почту приходить письмо с логином и паролем. Все хорошо, но любой кто узнает мыло будет тоже вводить его мыло в поле для восстановления и тому будет приходить письмо.

Comment: Что за бред? Письмо будет приходить на тот ящик, который указали в форме.... Делайте смену пароля при нажатии спец. Ссылки в теле письма!

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли, любой кто узнает E-mail того пользователя который не хотел восстанавливать пароль, а какой нибудь школьник будет баловаться и на почту будут приходить письма.

Comment: Хранящиеся пароли нужно шифровать с md5 или еще как-нибудь. Как сказал @KoVadim пароль стоит сбрасывать, а не отправлять.

Comment: Ну пусть приходят письма. Пароль при этом не должен сбрасываться.

Comment: При каждой попытке сброса пароля для одного аккаунта записывать в сессию счётчик +1 . Время жизни сессии сутки. Если было больше определённого количества попыток отказывать в сбросе на некоторое время.

Comment: Восстановить пароль,отправить на электронную почту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно присылать пароль. Нужно присылать ссылку на сброс пароля. Если пользователь в течении часа (суток) не кликнул по ссылке, то она стает недействительной.

До тех пор, пока пользователь не кликнет по ссылке, пароль сбрасывать не нужно.

Сброс пароля - это просто предложение ввести новый пароль.